# Emacs stalls when opening Python files

Tags: python

I recently upgraded to (K)ubuntu 16.04 which includes Emacs 24.5.1. Since the upgrade, Emacs stalls for more than three minutes when opening any Python file. The problem occurs when opening a new Python file as well as on existing files. I tried eg.

emacs --no-init-file example.py

where the file can be a literal hello world program, non existing or any small Python script. The problem also occurs when opening a Python file after editing other files or when using dired to open the file. I left no extensions installed on that system.

CPU load and memory footprint are normal while Emacs stalls (below 1% on my system). Ctrl+G allows circumventing the problem. Once the first Python file has loaded, all other Python files load normally w/out delay.

I tried removing all configuration files

```
rm -r .emacs*
```

but that did not help either (note that I could not reproduce the problem on other (K)Ubuntu systems). The only message I get from Emacs is likely not related: "Warning: no abbrev-file found, customize `abbrev-file-name' in order to make mode-specific abbrevs work.". How can I get Emacs to be usable for editing Python files again?  Any hints are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Do you see the same problem even when you do `emacs -Q example.py`? Note that the `-Q` option is different than `-q`.

Comment: Possibly sounds like a symptom of this: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/18438/50

Comment: According to your answer it's too late, but for this kind of problem setting `debug-on-quit` can get a backtrace from hitting Ctrl+G which is usually helpful for solving.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue, I first ruled out the configuration and local elpa packages. After making sure that the same issue does not reproduce on other installations w/ the same emacs version, the remaining cause could only be buried in the system configuration. After re-installing all emacs related packages and removing all emacs related python extensions from the system (there were yasnippets, emacs-goodies-el, pylint etc.), the problem was resolved. Unfortunately, I don't know which of the packages caused the problem.