# Magit Status Runs Very Slowly

Tags: magit

I installed the `magit` package via Marmalade. When I run M-x magit-status it takes a long time to run and complete (about 30 seconds). How can I speed this up?

Comment: The question risks being closed as too broad or unclear. Please specify exactly what you have tried.

Comment: See http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/19440/5296; if it's only slow on first `magit-status`, also see http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/19110/5296

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I installed the `magit` package via Marmalade.

The `magit` package on Marmalade is no longer being updated, because the maintainer of Marmalade has stopped actually maintaining it. Before I gave up on Marmalade, I had some technical issues when trying to upload new releases and it was very hard to get the maintainer to help me.

The last release that is available from Marmalade is `v2.4.1` but the current release is `v2.7.0`. Furthermore I believe the manuals are missing from the `v2.4.1` tarball available from Marmalade, because Marmalade decided that the original tarball was to large and I had to remove the documentation to make it smaller. Otherwise I would not have been able to upload a new tarball at all.

That was the final straw and I decided to no longer attempt to upload new releases to Marmalade.

I suspect that many other packages also are no longer being updated on Marmalade. While it is still possible to upload new releases and (probably) new packages, that is only the case if you already have a Marmalade account. If you want to create a new account to be able to upload new packages, then you are out of luck - the maintainer does not respond to such (or any other) requests.

Marmalade is dying a slow death and you should move to Melpa or Melpa stable.

> How can I speed this up?

Updating to `v2.7.0` should help. Performance has improved since `v2.4.1`.

If that's not enough, then see [the info node dedicated to performance issues](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Performance.html).